# Как можно полностью заменить один объект на другой в JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно, что бы при нажатии на элемент, на его место вставал другой, который первоначально `display: none`. При этом не просто вставал, а вообще удалял первый. Реализовал, что бы элемент выходил по клику по тому, который должен уйти, а он тупо двигается и даёт место для второго.
Пишу так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.high').click(function() {
        $('.high').removeClass('high');
    });
});
```

Но ничего не выходит.
Есть такой код:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="high"><a href="#" onmouseover="openbox('button'); return false"> <img id="high" src="red-heart-outline-clip-art-1257470.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="button"><a href="#" onclick="openbox('buy'); return false"> <img  id="button" class="animated infinite pulse" src="red-heart-outline-clip-art-12574701.png"/></a></div>
    <div class="buy"><img id="buy" class="animated infinite pulse" src="red-heart-outline-clip-art-1257470.png"/></div>
</div>
```

Ввожу в html

```
<script>
    $('.high').hover(function() {
        $(this).replaceWith($('.button'));
    });
</script>
```

И тоже ничего не выходит.

**Весь код:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.high').click(function() {
    $('.high').fadeOut(2);
    $('.button').fadeIn(2);
  });
});
```

```css
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-image: url('Old.jpg');
    }
    .main {
      overflow: hidden;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    .high {
      position: fixed;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .high img {
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
    .button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .button img {
      display: none;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    }
    .buy {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .buy img {
      display: none;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="Hello.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="Hello.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="high">
      <a href="#">
        <img id="high" src="red-heart-outline-clip-art-1257470.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
      <a href="#">
        <img id="button" class="animated infinite pulse" src="red-heart-outline-clip-art-12574701.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="buy">
      <img id="buy" class="animated infinite pulse" src="red-heart-outline-clip-art-1257470.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  </boby>

</html>
```

Comment: `romoveClass` -> `removeClass`

Comment: Ошибся, но в самом коде всё правильно и не работает.

Comment: "на его место вставал другой", "вообще удалял" - как это сочетается с `removeClass`? Может Вам нужен `jQuery.replaceWith` http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/?

Comment: <div class="main">
<div class="high"><a href="#" onmouseover="openbox('button'); return false"> <img id="high" class="hello" src="red-heart-outline-clip-art-1257470.png"/></a></div>
<div class="button"><a href="#" onclick="openbox('buy'); return false"> <img  id="button" class="animated infinite pulse" src="red-heart-outline-clip-art-1257470.png"/></a></div>
<div class="buy"><img id="buy" class="animated infinite pulse" src="red-heart-outline-clip-art-1257470.png"/></div>
</div>  Пишу в html    $('.high').click(function() {
  $('this').replaceWith( $('.button'));
 });  и ничего.

Comment: @D.N.JELL перенесите код в вопрос. В комментариях он нечитабелен.

Comment: Тут есть специальные сниппеты для демонстрации работы кода на лету. (Как jsfiddle).

Answer (score 3):

```js
//Убираем первый и показываем второй
$(function(){
    $('.cl-1').click(function() {
        $('.cl-1').fadeOut(2);
        $('.cl-2').fadeIn(2);
    });
});

//Убираем второй и показываем первый
$(function(){
    $('.cl-2').click(function() {
        $('.cl-2').fadeOut(2);
        $('.cl-1').fadeIn(2);
    });
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  }

.cl-1 {
   width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  }

.cl-2 {
  display: none;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <div class="cl-1"></div>
  <div class="cl-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня и это не выходит. Применил к себе и подставил свои значения классов. Так же мёртво, как и раньше. Может кофликт с чем может быть?

Comment: UPD. Добавил в шапку полные коды проекта.

Comment: попробуй заменить `<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>` на `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Понял в чём была ошибка, спасибо за помощь! Дело было не в jquery,  а где писал скрипт.